# How can I remove and purge EasyScreenCast from Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, application-development

I typed `sudo apt remove easyscreencast` and I got the result:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package easyscreencast
```

So anyone can explain me how to remove and purge EasyScreenCast?

Comment: I want to remove it from Ubuntu, I don't want to see it anymore.

Comment: @Terrance It doesn't work. https://yadi.sk/i/1BOT3sEoI6klBA

Comment: I followed the steps from https://linuxhint.com/installing_gnome_extensions_ubuntu/ , I typed `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks` and it works fine to turn it off.

Comment: Feel free to add that as your answer.  I spaced off GNOME Tweaks, but yep, that is another way of turning off GNOME Shell Extensions.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the application called Tweaks, I can turn it off. I followed the steps from the [website](https://linuxhint.com/installing_gnome_extensions_ubuntu/).**

Open the terminal and type the following:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
    sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
```

And then, open Tweaks and turn if off.

Later I found how to remove it, go to there: https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and then, click X. That's all.